# How to implement HTTP endpoint in Micronaut to pause consumption of messages from Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, micronaut

let my describe the rationale behind my question:

- We have a Micronaut-based application consuming messages from Kafka broker.
- The consumed messages are processed and fed to another remote "downstream" application.
- If this downstream application is going to restart purposely, it will take a while to get ready accepting further messages from our Micronaut-based application.

So we have the idea to send out Micronaut application a request to SUSPEND/PAUSE consumption of messages from Kafka (e.g. via HTTP to an appropriate endpoint).
The KafkaConsumer interface seems to have appropriate methods to achieve this goal like

```
public void pause​(java.util.Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
public void resume​(java.util.Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

But how to get a reference to the appropriate KafkaConsumer instance fed in to our HTTP endpoint?

We've tried to get it injected to the constructor of the HTTP endpoint/controller class, but this yields

```
Error instantiating bean of type  [HttpController]
Message: Missing bean arguments for type: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer. Requires arguments: AbstractKafkaConsumerConfiguration consumerConfiguration
```

It's possible to get a reference of KafkaConsumer instance as method parameter with @Topic annotated receive methods as describes in the [Micronaut Kafka documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaOffsets),
but this would result in storing this reference as instance variable, get it accessed by the HTTP endpoint, etc. pp. ... which sounds not very convincing:
You get a reference to the KafkaConsumer ONLY when receiving the next message! This might by appropriate for SUSPENDING/PAUSING, but not for RESUMING!

By the way, calling KafkaConsumer.resume(...) on a reference saved as instance variable yields

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:2201)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquireAndEnsureOpen(KafkaConsumer.java:2185)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.resume(KafkaConsumer.java:1842)
    [...]
```

I think the same holds true when implementing KafkaConsumerAware interface to store a reference of the freshly created KafkaConsumer instance.

So are there any ideas how to handle this in an appropriate way?

Thanks

Christian

Comment: Implementing `io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.ConsumerAware`, saving the `Consumer` instances, and later on Invoking on them
`Consumer.unsubscribe()`, or
`Consumer.subscribe("example-topic")`
fails with `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, too.

Comment: Synchronizing access to `Consumer` instance variables (as proposed by [Javadoc chapter "Multi-threaded Processing"](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) doesn't help, either.

Comment: Seems that under the hood Micronaut launches a separate Thread for running each `KafkaConsumer` (described [here](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaListener)), which is unaccessible for business code, so no appropriate synchronization on the `Consumer` instances is possible.

Comment: Has been put to an [Issue](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka/issues/19).